# How to ask a question in R when running the R script in linux?

Tags: linux, r

I wrote a code in R which has 2 variables in it: rep & x
the code is written in a way that I should go inside the script to change the values for X and rep variables depends on the input data. I am wondering how can I automate this instead of going inside the script:

```
rm(list=ls())  
ls()           

data<-read.table(file="data.txt", header=T) 
colnames(data)  

rep<-1000 

x <- 88

diff_debv<-matrix(,nr=rep,nc=1)   
for (i in 1:rep) {        
  
  
  N<-nrow(data)    
  m1<-runif(1)    
  
  m2<-runif(1)     
  sd1<-runif(1)   
  sd2<-runif(1)   
  
  
  x1<-rnorm(N,m1,sd1)  
  x2<-rnorm(N,m2,sd2) 
  data0<-cbind(data,x1,x2)  
  data1<-data0[with(data0,order(-x1)),]  
  top40_x1 <-data1[1:x,]              
  dEBV2019_1 <- mean(top40_x1$run.15564)  
  data2<-data0[with(data0,order(-x2)),] 
   
  top40_x2<-data2[1:x,]                
   
  dEBV2019_2 <- mean(top40_x2$run.15564) 
  
  diff_debv[i,1]<-(dEBV2019_1-dEBV2019_2)
   
}

sd.diff_debv <- sd(diff_debv)

sd.diff_debv

data3<-data0[with(data0,order(-GEBV2017)),] 
data4<-data0[with(data0,order(-EBV2017)),]

top40_GEBV2017<- data3[1:x,]
top40_EBV2017<-data4[1:x,]
mean_top40_GEBV2017 <- mean(top40_GEBV2017$GEBV2017)
mean_top40_EBV2017 <- mean(top40_EBV2017$EBV2017)
diff_rank<-(mean_top40_GEBV2017-mean_top40_EBV2017)
type1_debv <- 1-(pnorm(diff_rank, 0, sd.diff_debv))
diff_rank 
sd.diff_debv 
type1_debv
```

I want instead of going inside the script each time to change the values of x and rep, when I run the script in linux, 2 questions appear, and after answering to those question the script executes accordingly.  for example:

```
R < script.r > result
what is the value for rep?
1000
what is the value for x?
88
```

Is there any function in R to such a work? any help or guidance will be appreciated.

Comment: Why not use the language's own capabilities to accept user input? [R Program to Take Input From User](https://www.datamentor.io/r-programming/examples/user-input/)

Comment: @Haxiel thanks for suggestion but even with this I an get what I want, yet I have to go into script and save my values in  there

Comment: How about command-line arguments? You run your script as `command arg1 arg2`, and the script gets the values arg1 and arg2. There is a QA here: [How can I read command line parameters from an R script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2151212/6216002)